# Etymology of "chatterbox"

Tags: etymology

[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=chatterbox&searchmode=none) dates *chatterbox* to 1774, understandably as a concatenation of the words chatter and box.

To me, it seems like the connection stems from "a heavy blow of gossip/chatter".

When was this word first used and in what context, more specifically as a noun?

Comment: No, it's *box* as container, not *box* as in fighting. Someone might be able to post some OED citation data.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Thanks, Andrew.  I couldn't decide on which variation of *box* it was and thought the blow to be more likely.  Rethinking it, however, a box of chatter describing a person does seem more likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *OED*'s first citation is

> 1774   C. Clive *Let.* 13 Jan. in D. Garrick *Private Corr.* (1831) I. 604   But I suppose his father can, for he is a fine chatter-box.

but it's easy to find a couple of antedatings:

> 1761   C. Morell [*The History of James Lovegrove, Esq*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=F1dCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA95) II 95   Hold, hold Chatter-box! To your Buſineſs—
>   1762   [*Monthly Review* Vol. XXVI](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CJdKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA112) 112   a ratting braggadocio, a conceited fop, an eternal chatter-box!

Neither citation sheds any light on the etymology. But I note that **prattle-box** is obviously formed on the same lines as *chatter-box* and appears somewhat earlier:

> 1671   J. Glanvill *Disc. H. Stubbe* 2   Gross Ignoramusses, Illiterate Fools, Prattle-boxes, Catch-Dotterels,..Tories, Cheats, and poor Devils.

And **prattle-basket** is even earlier:

> 1602   N. Breton *Mothers Blessing* sig. E1   But if she be ilfauour'd, blind, and old, A prattle basket, or an idle slut.

I think these earlier forms provide support for *chatter-box* being originally understood as "a container full of idle talk".

Answer (score 2):

The OED also shows the first use of *chatterbox* as being 1774. It suggests ‘perhaps in origin akin to *clapdish*’, ‘a wooden dish with a lid, formerly carried by lepers, beggars from the lazar-houses, and mendicants generally, to give warning of their approach, and to receive alms.’ It had a secondary meaning, now obsolete, as ‘jocularly used of a talkative mouth.’ I don't think the OED comment means that *chatterbox* is a phonetic corruption of *clapdish*, but rather that a chatterbox might once have been something like a clapdish.