# Why is helleborine sometimes called 'chatterbox'?

Tags: etymology

I found out now, thanks to the question about the [etymology of chatterbox](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76494/etymology-of-chatterbox), that 'chatterbox' is another name for helleborine (something I've never heard of). A helleborine is apparently

> an orchid growing along streams or ponds of western North America having leafy stems and one greenish-brown and pinkish flower in the axil of each upper leaf

What could possible be the etymology for this?

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chatterbox

Comment: *helleborine* means *like hellebore,* which is a completely different plant that looks simmilar. Hellebore comes from the Greek *helleboros*, which *etymonline* says [may mean](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hellebore) *plant eaten by fawns*.

Comment: So why is it called 'chatterbox'? Is my source accurate? Because I couldn't find it on MW.

Comment: The origins of common names of plants can be obscure. There is presumably some feature of the helleborine which once reminded someone of a talkative person. This, however, is unlikely to have any bearing on the etymology of ‘chatterbox’ itself.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. What should I do with the question?

Comment: Image search for "chatterbox orchid" says yes, it's accurate. The oldest source among [google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=68vGzAWT28MC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=chatterbox+orchid&source=bl&ots=klQdp7lj8p&sig=HlP0BiKIiqfl6m8UecApZPvT_0k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ccAXUOaPHsbw0gHf44HgCQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=chatterbox%20orchid&f=false) I could find for this is 1999, and it gives no clue as to the etymology. And it is only a specific species of helleborine that is called *chatterbox*.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I saw that it was a specific species. Maybe it made a lot of noise when wind passed through it :)

Comment: What is now your question?

Comment: Quite amusing: [this website](http://www.dictionarylink.com/babbler) gives "giant helleborine" as a synonym for "babbler". Some automatic search program is out of control.

Comment: I don't have anything else - I wanted to know why this plant was called "chatterbox", and your answer was convincing. @PeterShor I see!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Chatterbox Orchid* [Epipactis Sabine Frankfurt](http://www.norwellnurseries.co.uk/plant/?name=Epipactis%20Sabine%20Frankfurt), also known as *Helleborine, Stream Orchid* is so called because of a fancied resemblance to an open (talking) mouth...

[image: Chatterbox Orchid] [image] (the [Rolling Stones logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Rolling_Stones_Tongue_Logo.png) for comparison).